# Performance degradation after solution upgrade from .net 4 to 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net, performance, garbage-collection, .net-4.6.1

I've upgraded my solution from .net 4.0 to .net 4.6.1 and observed some weird behavior.

I have a program and in this program I have a sequence (call it **sequence1**) that reads binary files of arrays of doubles and saving the data in the RAM.

Before the upgrade whenever I ran this **sequence1** (the program is single threaded) the machine used 25% of the CPU (in a 4 cores machine).
This behavior changed since the upgrade, if I start my program with **sequence1** I get normal behavior (the sequence runs at 25%) but if before **sequence1** I run something that does some arithmetic calculations and allocating some classes let's call it **sequence0**, then when I get to the **sequence1** it uses 70-90% of the CPU.

I think this may be connected to the garbage collection mechanism. I've tried setting all the classes to null and call `GC.Collect` right after **sequence0** (before calling **sequence1**) but I still get **sequence1** that runs at 70-90%; perhaps this is related to the GC algorithm that updated it's threshes while doing **sequence0**?

Comment: Maybe `gcConcurrent` is active now? You can play with the behavior in the app.config file. Main question is, is it faster now? Could also be PGO (see one of my top questions).

Comment: You need to profile the performance of your application instead of making guesses at the problem.  To start with you should look at the perfmon counters for .NET and compare the two runs with these to see what's different.

Comment: @Paolo, I'll try perfmon and compare but even without the comparison a single threaded program shouldn't rise above 25% (let alone 90%), should it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the upgrade to 4.6.1 may cause a GC.Collect() call to take longer, 
try to check if there are any explicit calls to garbage collection.
this also explains why you get more CPU usage after you've done the jobs that allocated memory, if there are more allocated objects then garbage collection will take longer

Comment: looks like you were right, I found and remove one GC call, run it again a CPU usage didn't rise. It looks like .net 4.6 likes to handles GC collection automatically, now all I have to do is try and remember why I had this call in the first place.